# Prisma NodeJS: Include ID in query

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

Model:

```
model Foo {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    name String
    bar Bar?
}

model Bar {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    name String
    foo Foo @relation(fields: [fooId], references: [id])
    fooId Int
}
```

Node Code:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

async function main() {
   let client = new PrismaClient();
   let foo = client.foo.findFirst( ??? )
};

main()
```

**What goes in the ??? to get an object that includes both `Foo` and `Bar`'s IDs (as well as all the other fields once the model gets bigger)?**

Note that if possible, it shouldn't use `select` since in a larger model I'd need to list out every field including `id` which I am not up to do. If there isn't any alternative other than raw SQL, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[As of the documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference):

```
const result = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: 42,
  },
})
```

So, in your case:

```
client.foo.findFirst( ??? )
```

Would become:

```
client.foo.findFirst({
     where: {
          id: yourvaluehere
     }
})
```

Comment: Also, as a side note, you should probably use `const` instead of `let` if you don't need to modify your variable afterwards (which looks like the case in your example and in most cases)